# Can $x^n = 1$ describe the equation of a unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, real-numbers

The complex roots of the equation $x^n = 1$ lie on the unit circle.

Suppose $n$ goes large. Is it correct to say that  all the roots of $x^n=1$ form  a circle of radius one?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. And no, it's not true that every point on the unit circle $S^1 \subset \Bbb C$ satisfies $x^n-1=0$ for some $n$; what about, say, $\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$?

Comment: @MikeMiller: The length of every root is $1$. The larger $n$ gets, the more roots you have. So the question makes quite good sense in that aspect.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, I agree: Behaviour's edit makes this a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, strictly speaking, the set of points $x$ in the complex plane satisfying $x^n-1=0$ for some $n$ is exactly the set of points $e^{i\pi r}$ for rational $r$ - that is, any point on the unit circle whose argument is a rational number times $\pi$. This set is *dense* in the unit circle, but it's not the whole unit circle by a long shot.

However, we can characterize the unit circle as the points $x$ such that
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x^n-1| = 0$$
since the argument of $x^n$, as $n$ increases, will be dense mod $2\pi$ if it is not a rational multiple of $2\pi$, and it's trivial to show that if $|x|<1$, then the above limit is $1$, and if $|x|>1$, the above limit is $\infty$, sufficing to show that the above describes exactly the unit circle.

Answer (score 12):

No luck there. Note that for every $n$, $x^n-1$ has $n$ roots, so it only generates $n$ points on the unit circle.

Even if we take the union over all integer $n$ of the roots of $x^n-1$, we only have a countable number of points while there are an uncountable number of points on the unit circle.

Comment: Two questions (one related to your answer, and the other not related to your answer): 1. How do you show that there are an uncountable number of points on the unit circle? 2. What if we use every real value of $n$ - will that cover all the points on the unit circle?

Comment: @barakmanos For the first, we can use a bijection (think 2D stereographic projection) between the unit circle (minus a point) and the real line. In particular, we can map the point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle to $\frac{x}{1-y}$ (this is just a 2D cross-section of the standard stereographic projection).

Comment: @barakmanos I think the answer to the second question is yes, we can cover all the points like that. In particular, we take the representation of any particular point as $e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and then consider $n=\dfrac{2\pi}{\theta}$ (noting that we can discount the case $\theta=0$). Then we have $(e^{i\theta})^n=e^{2\pi i}=1$, so $e^{i\theta}$ is then a solution to $x^n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the answer is no.

The length of every root of $x^n=1$ is $1$.

The larger $n$ gets, the more roots you have.

So your question makes quite good sense in that aspect.

But the roots of $x^n=1$ are $(k\cos\frac{2\pi}{n},k\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})$ for $k\in[0,n-1]$.

In other words, only complex numbers whose angle with the axises is an integer multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Since there are infinitely many points on the unit circle whose angle with the axises is **not** an integer multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, these roots will never "cover it completely" (no matter how large $n$ gets).